# user access to private directory

Tags: permissions

`User1` should have **write access** to to download a file *“person”* to *rooted* directory, `/bucket`, but not being allowed to do anything else to the directory.

`User2` needs **read access** to file *“person”* in *rooted* directory, `/bucket`, and import file *“person”* into `User2` server.

How do I set the permission on rooted directory, `/bucket`, and user permission for the above users?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what "rooted directory" means? Also you didn't specify a linux distro so my commands will be based on Ubuntu.

Without an ACL your options are limited. I'm assuming you want neither of these users to own the /bucket directory. Create a group (we'll call it "readers" in my example) and add User2 to group "readers".

```
addgroup readers
adduser User2 readers
```

Give group ownership of the /bucket directory to "readers".

```
chgrp readers /bucket
```

Now you can give the readers group read permissions on the /bucket directory and set "other" to only have write permission (no read). We're also setting the sticky bit to prevent those with write permission from deleting other user's files.

```
chmod 1753 /bucket
```

The permissions should look like this when you're done

```
drwxr-x-wt 1 root   readers     0 Feb 26 17:08 bucket
```

This gives root full control, readers can read but not write, and everyone else can write to the directory but not read.

If you require more granular control (i.e. permissions on a per user basis) you'll need to look into using an ACL.  To use an ACL we'll change the process above a little bit.

First create a group that will contain both users.  In my example we'll call this group "bucket-users".

```
addgroup bucket-users
adduser User1 bucket-users
adduser User2 bucket-users
```

Next we'll give the group bucket-users *full control* of the /bucket directory. We'll again want the sticky bit to prevent User1 from deleting files he didn't place in that directory.

```
chmod 1770 /bucket
```

The permissions should look like this when you're done.

```
drwxrwx--T  1 root    bucket-users 0 Feb 26 17:08 bucket
```

Next we'll use the setfacl command to further limit the permissions of these users.

```
setfacl -m "u:User1:-wx" /bucket
setfacl -m "u:User2:r-x" /bucket
```

You can then verify these permissions with the getfacl command.

```
$ getfacl bucket
# file: bucket
# owner: root
# group: bucket-users
# flags: --t
user::rwx
user:User1:-wx
user:User2:r-x
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
```

Comment: @sourcejedi We're in the "Unix & Linux" exchange and I already do this in the 1st sentence of my response.

Comment: Oops. Sorry! It's the other Unixes I was concerned about, the same commands probably work on most Linux distributions.